# Using Bibentry Package with XeLatex Compiler

Tags: bibtex, templates

I am using the following Latex template for my CV:

https://www.latextemplates.com/template/awesome-resume-cv

However, the template does not come with an example on how to have a section on Publications and how to use bibentry package to create automatically the required publications as a list. Because of that I did the following changes to the template to automatically print the publications in a separate section from a biblio file:

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{awesome-cv} % A4 paper size by default, use 'letterpaper' for US letter

\usepackage{bibentry}

\geometry{left=2cm, top=1.5cm, right=2cm, bottom=2cm, footskip=.5cm} % Configure page margins with geometry

\fontdir[fonts/] % Specify the location of the included fonts

\colorlet{awesome}{awesome-darknight} % Default colors include: awesome-emerald, awesome-skyblue, awesome-red, awesome-pink, awesome-orange, awesome-nephritis, awesome-concrete, awesome-darknight

\renewcommand{\acvHeaderSocialSep}{\quad\textbar\quad} % If you would like to change the social information separator from a pipe (|) to something else

\name{}
\address{}
\mobile{}

\email{}
\github
\linkedin{}

\makecvfooter{}{~~~·~~~Résumé}{\thepage} % Specify the letter footer with 3 arguments: (<left>, <center>, <right>), leave any of these blank if they are not needed

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{document}

\nobibliography{biblio}
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}

\makecvheader % Print the header

\section*{Publications}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item \bibentry{module}
    \item \bibentry{module_ext}
\end{enumerate}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\end{document}
```

However, the template requires compilation using XeLatex. When I compile the latex file, I get the following error:

```
lonely \item--perhaps a missing list environment.
```

Note: I have already compiled the biblio file using BibTex. So what could be the problem?

Comment: Are you aware of the `biblatex-publist` package, which is specifically designed for that?

Comment: No, I am not aware of it. I always use `bibentry` package. Could you please provide an example for `biblatex-publist`?

Comment: This is a comparatively recent package. There is an example in the (short) documentation.  Among other features, you can split your bibliography by type, say, articles,books, alone or in collaboration, &c.

Comment: I added the following:

`\usepackage[backend=bibtex8, bibstyle=publist]{biblatex}
\plauthorname[first name][von-part]{surname}
\addbibresource{biblio.bib}`

Then in the Publications Section, I add `\printbibliography` but it does not print anything even though I compiled with Bibtex.

Comment: Did you run `bibtex8`? (better compile the bibliography with `biber`, though). The normal cycle is `pdflatex -> bibtex (or biber) -> pdflatex (twice)` to resolve all the references.

Comment: I tried with both `bibtex` and `biber` and then I executed `XeLatex` twice because the template can be only compiled with `XeLatex ` and nothing is being printed. I am using TexWork as Editor.

Comment: What does the .blg file say? Do you have any .bbl file?

Comment: The answer below already solved my problem. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add also `\usepackage{natbib}` and change `\bibliographystyle{unsrt}` to `\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat}`.

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{awesome-cv} % A4 paper size by default, use 'letterpaper' for US letter

\usepackage{natbib,bibentry}

\geometry{left=2cm, top=1.5cm, right=2cm, bottom=2cm, footskip=.5cm} % Configure page margins with geometry

%\fontdir[fonts/] % Specify the location of the included fonts

\colorlet{awesome}{awesome-darknight} % Default colors include: awesome-emerald, awesome-skyblue, awesome-red, awesome-pink, awesome-orange, awesome-nephritis, awesome-concrete, awesome-darknight

\renewcommand{\acvHeaderSocialSep}{\quad\textbar\quad} % If you would like to change the social information separator from a pipe (|) to something else

\name{Some}{Name}
\address{Whatever}
\mobile{555-555-555}

\email{a@b}
\github{xyz}
\linkedin{abc}

\makecvfooter{}{~~~·~~~Résumé}{\thepage} % Specify the letter footer with 3 arguments: (<left>, <center>, <right>), leave any of these blank if they are not needed

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{document}

\nobibliography{biblio}
\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat}

\makecvheader % Print the header

\section*{Publications}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item \bibentry{module}
    \item \bibentry{module_ext}
\end{enumerate}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Your answer solved my problem. But is there a way to make a specific author appears in Bold?

Comment: @IoT For that you should switch to `biblatex`

Comment: If I do the switching to biblatex, then I run to the same problems above in my previous comments